# Is the term "given" is synonym to "according to" or "because of" in the following text?

Tags: synonyms, alternatives

Here is some text I have grabbed from a **Programming languages** book:

> As mentioned earlier, REST APIs are “a lightweight way to transfer
> textual representations of resources.” What do we mean by this? Well,
> when you make a call to retrieve data from a REST API, the data will
> be  returned to you in some serialized, textual format, for example:
>
> • JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
>
> • Extensible Markup Language (XML)
>
> • Hypertext Markup Language (HTML)
>
> • Yet Another Markup Language (YAML)
>
> and so on. Upon receiving that serialized string payload, you’ll then
> do something with it, most  likely some kind of deserialization
> operation so you can use the resource or object within  the consuming
> application. With regard to REST APIs, there is no prescribed payload
> format, although most usually JSON will be used and returned. We will
> be using JSON as  our payload format in this book **given** its
> lightweight nature and ubiquity in the industry.

Now, my question is that: Can I describe the bold **given** above as "according to" or "because of" so that I have the following sentence after replacing the alternatives:

> We will be using JSON as our payload format in this book **because of/according to** its
> lightweight nature and ubiquity in the industry.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/given) has **given**: (Preposition) Taking into account. *Given the complexity of the task, they did a good job*. Why do you need to change it?

Comment: "according to" makes no sense, "because of" works here

Answer (score 2):

You could use "because of" (but not "according to") but, as @WeatherVane has mentioned, "given" is just the right word here. It fits in like a glove. No need to change it.

**Given** means **when you consider...**, **when we take into account...**

In your text:

*We will be using JSON as our payload format in this book **given** its lightweight nature and ubiquity in the industry.*

Means:

*We will be using JSON as our payload format in this book **considering** its lightweight nature and ubiquity in the industry.*

More examples from this use of given (as a preposition) from Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries:

> *Given his age (= considering how old he is), he's remarkably active.
>
> Given her interest in children, teaching seems the right job for her.
>
> Given (the fact) that he's had six months to do this, he hasn't made much progress.*

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute **because of** for **given** in your example. Other substitutions include **due to**, **for** and **considering**.

**According to** is **not** a correct substitution.